# Store variables from lines in a text file using awk and cut in a for loop

Tags: bash, unix, awk, cut

I have a tab separated text file, call it `input.txt`

```
cat input.txt
Begin   Annotation      Diff    End     Begin,End
6436687 >ENST00000422706.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|-|APOL1-205|APOL1|2901|protein_coding|       50      6436736 6436687,6436736
6436737 >ENST00000426053.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|-|APOL1-206|APOL1|2808|protein_coding|       48      6436784 6436737,6436784
6436785 >ENST00000319136.8|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000075315.5|APOL1-201|APOL1|3000|protein_coding|    51      6436835 6436785,6436835
6436836 >ENST00000422471.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319151.1|APOL1-204|APOL1|561|nonsense_mediated_decay|    11      6436846 6436836,6436846
6436847 >ENST00000475519.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319153.1|APOL1-212|APOL1|600|retained_intron|    11      6436857 6436847,6436857
6436858 >ENST00000438034.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319152.2|APOL1-210|APOL1|566|protein_coding|     11      6436868 6436858,6436868
6436869 >ENST00000439680.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319252.1|APOL1-211|APOL1|531|nonsense_mediated_decay|    10      6436878 6436869,6436878
6436879 >ENST00000427990.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319154.2|APOL1-207|APOL1|624|protein_coding|     12      6436890 6436879,6436890
6436891 >ENST00000397278.8|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319100.4|APOL1-202|APOL1|2795|protein_coding|    48      6436938 6436891,6436938
6436939 >ENST00000397279.8|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|-|APOL1-203|APOL1|1564|protein_coding|       28      6436966 6436939,6436966
6436967 >ENST00000433768.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319253.2|APOL1-209|APOL1|541|protein_coding|     11      6436977 6436967,6436977
6436978 >ENST00000431184.1|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319254.1|APOL1-208|APOL1|550|nonsense_mediated_decay|    11      6436988 6436978,6436988
```

Using the information in input.txt I want to obtain information from a file called Other_File.fa. This file is an annotation file filled with ENST#'s (transcript IDs) and sequences of A's,T's,C's,and G's. I want to store the sequence in a file called Output.log (see example below) and I want to store the command used to retrieve the text in a file called Input.log (see example below).

I have tried to do this using awk and cut so far using a for loop. This is the code I have tried.

```
for line in `awk -F "\\t" 'NR != 1 {print substr($2,2,17)"@"$5}' input.txt`
do
transcript=`cut -d "@" -f 1 $line`
range=`cut -d "@" -f 2 $line` #Range is the string location in Other_File.fa
echo "Our transcript is ${transcript} and our range is ${range}" >> Input.log
sed -n '${range}' Other_File.fa >> Output.log
done
```

Here is an example of the 11 lines between ENST00000433768.5 and ENST00000431184.1 in Other_File.fa.

```
grep -A 11 ENST00000433768.5 Other_File.fa
>ENST00000433768.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319253.2|APOL1-209|APOL1|541|protein_coding|
ATCCACACAGCTCAGAACAGCTGGATCTTGCTCAGTCTCTGCCAGGGGAAGATTCCTTGG
AGGAGCACACTGTCTCAACCCCTCTTTTCCTGCTCAAGGAGGAGGCCCTGCAGCGACATG
GAGGGAGCTGCTTTGCTGAGAGTCTCTGTCCTCTGCATCTGGATGAGTGCACTTTTCCTT
GGTGTGGGAGTGAGGGCAGAGGAAGCTGGAGCGAGGGTGCAACAAAACGTTCCAAGTGGG
ACAGATACTGGAGATCCTCAAAGTAAGCCCCTCGGTGACTGGGCTGCTGGCACCATGGAC
CCAGGCCCAGCTGGGTCCAGAGGTGACAGTGGAGAGCCGTGTACCCTGAGACCAGCCTGC
AGAGGACAGAGGCAACATGGAGGTGCCTCAAGGATCAGTGCTGAGGGTCCCGCCCCCATG
CCCCGTCGAAGAACCCCCTCCACTGCCCATCTGAGAGTGCCCAAGACCAGCAGGAGGAAT
CTCCTTTGCATGAGAGCAGTATCTTTATTGAGGATGCCATTAAGTATTTCAAGGAAAAAG
T
>ENST00000431184.1|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319254.1|APOL1-208|APOL1|550|nonsense_mediated_decay|
```

The range value in input.txt for this transcript is 6436967,6436977. In my file Input.log for this transcript I hope to get

```
Our transcript is ENST00000433768.5 and our range is 6436967,6436977
```

And in Output.log for this transcript I hope to get

```
>ENST00000433768.5|ENSG00000100342.21|OTTHUMG00000030427.9|OTTHUMT00000319253.2|APOL1-209|APOL1|541|protein_coding|
ATCCACACAGCTCAGAACAGCTGGATCTTGCTCAGTCTCTGCCAGGGGAAGATTCCTTGG
AGGAGCACACTGTCTCAACCCCTCTTTTCCTGCTCAAGGAGGAGGCCCTGCAGCGACATG
GAGGGAGCTGCTTTGCTGAGAGTCTCTGTCCTCTGCATCTGGATGAGTGCACTTTTCCTT
GGTGTGGGAGTGAGGGCAGAGGAAGCTGGAGCGAGGGTGCAACAAAACGTTCCAAGTGGG
ACAGATACTGGAGATCCTCAAAGTAAGCCCCTCGGTGACTGGGCTGCTGGCACCATGGAC
CCAGGCCCAGCTGGGTCCAGAGGTGACAGTGGAGAGCCGTGTACCCTGAGACCAGCCTGC
AGAGGACAGAGGCAACATGGAGGTGCCTCAAGGATCAGTGCTGAGGGTCCCGCCCCCATG
CCCCGTCGAAGAACCCCCTCCACTGCCCATCTGAGAGTGCCCAAGACCAGCAGGAGGAAT
CTCCTTTGCATGAGAGCAGTATCTTTATTGAGGATGCCATTAAGTATTTCAAGGAAAAAG
T
```

But I am getting the following error, and I am unsure as to why or how to fix it.

```
cut: ENST00000433768.5@6436967,6436977: No such file or directory
cut: ENST00000433768.5@6436967,6436977: No such file or directory
Our transcript is  and our range is
```

My thought was each line from the awk would be read as a string then cut could split the string along the "@" symbol I have added, but it is reading each line as a file and throwing an error when it can't locate the file in my directory.

Thanks.

Comment: With respect to `I want a for loop that can iterate line by line` - that is extremely unlikely to be the right approach to your problem, whatever that problem is. It's not at all clear what it is you actually want to do (as opposed to how you think you should do it), so far this seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please [edit] your question to clearly stare **what** it is you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT2:*** This is a generic solution which will compare 2 files(input and other_file.fa) and on whichever line whichever range is found it will print them. Eg--> Range numbers are found on 300 line number but range shows you should print from 1 to 20 it will work in that case also. Also note this calls system command which further calls `sed` command(like you were using range within `sed`), there are other ways too, like to load whole Input_file into an array or so and then print, but I am going with this one here, fair warning this is not tested with huge size files.

```
awk -F'[>| ]' '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$2]=$NF
  next
}
($2 in arr){
  split(arr[$2],lineNum,",")
  print arr[$2]
  start=lineNum[1]
  end=lineNum[2]
  print "sed -n \047" start","end"p \047 " FILENAME
  system("sed -n \047" start","end"p\047 " FILENAME)
  start=end=0
}
' file1 FS="[>|]" other_file.fa
```

---

***EDIT:*** With OP's edited samples, please try following to print lines based on other file. assumes that the line you find range values, those values will be always after the line on which they found(eg--> 3rd line range values found and range is 4 to 10).

```
awk -F'[>| ]' '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$2]=$NF
  next
}
($2 in arr){
  split(arr[$2],lineNum," ")
  start=lineNum[1]
  end=lineNum[2]
}
FNR>=start && FNR<=end{
  print
  if(FNR==end){
    start=end=0
  }
}
' file1 FS="[>|]" other_file.fa
```

---

---

You need not to do this with a for loop and then call `awk` program each time for each line. This could be done in single `awk`, considering that you have to only print them. Written and tested with your shown samples.

```
awk -F'[>| ]' 'FNR>1{print "Our transcript is:"$3" and our range is:"$NF}' Input_file
```

NOTE: This will print for each line of your Input_file values of transcript and range, in case you want to further perform some operation with their values then please do mention.

Comment: Your comment answered the question the way it was written, but I should have been more clear. I have made some edits above. I ultimately want to use the range value to search through a second file and retrieve the lines of text between the lower and upper limit on my range. My plan was to use sed to do this. I have altered my loop to include more detail.

Comment: @Ctat41, taking values from 1 file and compare to others can be done in a single `awk` itself, please update your question with sample of input and expected output and I can edit my answer then, cheers.

Comment: I have updated my question to include more detail, I want to obtain lines of text between each transcript from a second file. The lines in the range are the ones I want to extract.

Comment: @Ctat41, Sorry but your question is still not fully clear. If you could post samples of Other_File.file with expected output then it will be more clear and we can write in a single awk itself, update your question and let me know then.

Comment: @Ctat41, I have added EDIT code now, which assumes that the line you find range values, those values will be always after the line on which they found(eg--> 3rd line range values found and range is 4 to 10), let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Ctat41, please check my EDIT1 and EDIT2 answers and let me know how int goes.

Comment: EDIT1 gives me back the annotation info from input.txt, and doesn't seem to print the lines from Other_File.fa. EDIT2 is throwing ``` sed -n 'Begin   Annotation      Diff    End     Begin,Endp ' Other_File.fa ```